# Unable to run X11 applications remotely via XQuartz on a mac

Tags: ssh, x11, x11-forwarding, xquartz

I would like to run X11 applications on my remote FreeBSD box on my M1 mac.  I have installed XQuartz on the mac and connected to my remote FreeBSD box with X11 Forwarding enabled.

With these commands, I can see the DISPLAY is set, but when running any X program, I get "Cannot open display"

```
ssh -X user@box
ssh -Y user@box
```

This is a reference guide I followed:

https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/apple-osx-mountain-lion-mavericks-install-xquartz-server/